# Is it possible to detect the same image twice or more with ARKit's image recognition?

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm trying to build an app which detects the same image twice or more and adds these detected images to an array to do something with it later.

I added my image and size to the AR Resources folder in the Assets.xassets. The image gets recognized and that works fine. But when I want to scan the same image twice, it only recognises one image.

I didn't find any specific documentation for this problem on the internet. I also suspect that it isn't possible with ARKit and that I probably need to use a machine learning model.

If anyone has encountered this problem and has a solution without CoreML and Vision it would be appreciated. Otherwise I'll try to make it work with vision and CoreML.

Below is the code which recognises an image and ads a transparant plane above it.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
    let imageName = referenceImage.name ?? "no name"

    print("Image Anchor: ", imageAnchor)

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.opacity = 0.20
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    detectedImages.append(imageAnchor)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = "Image detected: \"\(imageName)\""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not recognise anything, it is called when ARKit has already added a default node for an anchor which was added for a recognised image, which indeed happens only once. In case to circumvent this limitation, follow the manual -

> Consider when to allow detection of each image to trigger (or repeat) AR interactions. ARKit adds an image anchor to a session exactly once for each reference image in the session configuration’s detectionImages array. If your AR experience adds virtual content to the scene when an image is detected, that action will by default happen only once. To allow the user to experience that content again without restarting your app, call the session’s remove(anchor:) method to remove the corresponding ARImageAnchor. After the anchor is removed, ARKit will add a new anchor the next time it detects the image.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.
You need to add an extra variable that stores the previously detected image and then compare it with the current image.
If they do not match it replaces the information on the previous image detected with the new one. This way if you have more than one image you can keep looking at one and the other and the content always shows up.

```
 last detected Image storage
    var lastImageAnchor: ARAnchor!

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        if self.lastImageAnchor != nil && self.lastImageAnchor != imageAnchor {
            self.sceneView.session.remove(anchor: self.lastImageAnchor)
        }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        let imageName = referenceImage.name ?? "no name"

        ... (insert the rest of your code here)...

        }
        self.lastImageAnchor = imageAnchor
    }
```

This should work.